# Как исказить аудио на python?

Tags: python-3.x, аудио

Я хочу сделать код, который будет аудиофайл с компьютера искажать, и получать что-то смешное(жмыхнуть, если вам угодно). Я так понял, что нужно это делать, как-то изменяя тон, но только какие-то инструменты, для изменения этого тона не нашёл.
Я бы хотел, чтобы на каждом моменте аудио тон изменялся на какое-то случайное число.
Буду рад, если поможете

Comment: Начните с каких-то библиотек для работы с аудио. `librosa` там и прочее. Поразбирайтесь.